# Oozie: rerun all non-SUCCEEDED workflows in coordinator

Tags: hadoop, oozie, oozie-coordinator

I scheduled a coordinator which initiated many individual workflows. This was a backfill coordinator, with both startdate and enddate in the past.

A small percentage of these jobs failed due to temporary issues with the input datasets, and now I need to re-run those workflows (without re-running the successful workflows). These unsuccessful workflows have a variety of statuses: KILLED, FAILED, and SUSPENDED.

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up writing a bash script to do this. I won't copy the whole script here, but this was the general outline:

First, parse the output of `oozie job -info` to get a list of actions with a given status for a given coordinator:

```
actions=$(oozie job -info $oozie_coord -filter status=$status -len 1000 |
          grep "\-C@" |
          awk '{print $1}' |
          sed -n "s/^.*@\([0-9]*\).*$/\1/p")
```

Then loop over these actions and issue rerun commands:

```
while read -r action; do
  oozie job -rerun $oozie_coord -action $action
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think whether the entire thing i.e. jobs with multiple statuses, can be run in a single command but with the `oozie jobs`, it can be attempted although three separate commands for the three statuses. If anyone else has a better approach, please post it.

```
oozie jobs filter -jobtype wf -filter status=<status> -resume
```

Ex:

```
# KILLED
oozie jobs filter -jobtype wf -filter status=SUSPENDED -resume
```

There are a whole lot of other sub-commands offered for `jobs` which can be viewed by `oozie help jobs`. Hope that helps!

Comment: Unfortunately, there are many Oozie workflows with e.g. status SUSPENDED that I don't want to re-run -- I only want to re-run the workflows associated with this particular coordinator. And adding an extra parameter to the call like `-filter name=my_coordinator_name` doesn't seem to actually perform any additional filtering.

Comment: That won't work, I think because we are providing the `jobtype` as wf and giving name=coord_name. Can you give the workflow name instead?

Comment: May be you can write a shell script with the list of failed, suspended, or killed jobs and iterate it using for loop and pass each job into the Oozie resume command